# Android listview top to down animation flashing when animating?

Tags: java, android, list, animation, notifydatasetchanged

I am running a top to down animation every time I update my listview, however, when I do this, the listview flashes white before it animates... is there any way I am able to fix this

Here is the method where I call the animation:

```
 public void updateDataList(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> newList){
    final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> newListAdd = newList;

        Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(
                liveStreamFragment.getActivity(), R.anim.top_to_down
        );
        anim.setDuration(2000);
        list.startAnimation(anim);

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {

                oslist.clear();
                oslist.addAll(newListAdd);
                LiveAdapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }

        }, anim.getDuration());

}
```

And here is my xml for R.anim.top_to_down

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<translate android:fromYDelta="20%p" android:toYDelta="-20"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"/>
<alpha android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime" />
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like it's an issue with the animation.

```
<alpha android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0"
android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime" />
```

`android:fromAlpha="0.0"` means that the item will start the animation with an alpha value of 0.0, meaning it will be completely transparent. `android:toAlpha="1.0"` then specifies that the item should animate towards an alpha value of 1.0, a.k.a. completely opaque.

If you want the item to fade out, which is typical for exit animations, you would want to switch the values.

```
<alpha android:fromAlpha="1.0" android:toAlpha="0.0"
android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime" />
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Do you know if there's any way that I can set my Ydelta in my java class? It's contingent upon the size of the row

Comment: @Teddy Wilson I'm not entirely clear how you plan to use the animation, but it is generally much easier and cleaner if you can keep your animations defined as static resources. It seems like you may already know this, but if you use, for example, 88% for the value of YDelta, then the final Y position for the item will be 0.88 * itemHeight. You could also use 88%p to represent 0.88 * parentHeight. Ideally, that should be able to handle most cases.

Comment: But if you still want to specify it programmatically, you would create a TranslateAnimation. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/TranslateAnimation.html